# My c function returns gibberish

Tags: c, function

So basically whenever I input a grade it gives me back a random symbol, even though I have defined grade. Wouldn't it better if i used the value from `return grade;` but I don't know how to retrieve that character into my main function :<

```
#include <stdio.h>

char GradeFromPercentage(float percentage);

int main() {
    float percentage1;
    printf("Enter the student's percentage:");
    scanf("%f", &percentage1);
    printf("Student's grade is %c \n", GradeFromPercentage(percentage1));
    return 0;
}

char GradeFromPercentage(float percentage) {
    char grade;
    if (percentage >= 90) {
        grade = "A";
    } else
    if (percentage >= 70) {
        grade = "B";
    } else
    if (percentage >= 50) {
        grade = "C";
    } else
    if (percentage >= 30) {
        grade = "D";
    } else {
        grade = "F";
    }
    return grade;
}
```

Comment: I wonder why the compiler didn't produce a warning. A good rule of thumb is to compile with as many warnings enabled as possible. If you use gcc, these options are handy: gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -std=c99 (or another standard).

Comment: `"A"` is not a `char`. Neither are `"B"`, `"C"`...

Comment: Compiler warning for each one.

Comment: `percentage` is a `float`, so any comparisons 'should' be to float values (implicit conversion will save you in this scenario, but you should do it right to begin with.  I.E. for these kinds of statements: `if (percentage >= 30)` it should be: `if (percentage >= 30.0f)`

Comment: when a char is surrounded with double quotes, it becomes a string literal and any assignment from that string literal will result in the address of that string literal.  When a char is surrounded with single quotes, then it becomes a char and any assignment from that char will result in that char.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Never trust the input supplied by the user, always verify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign strings to a `char` variable in `GradeFromPercentage()`. You should use character constants with single quotes instead of character strings with double quotes.

Here is a corrected and simplified version:

```
char GradeFromPercentage(float percentage) {
    if (percentage >= 90) {
        return 'A';
    }
    if (percentage >= 70) {
        return 'B';
    }
    if (percentage >= 50) {
        return 'C';
    }
    if (percentage >= 30) {
        return 'D';
    }
    return 'F';
}
```

Comment: one liner: `return "FFFDDCCBBA"[percentage < 0 ? 0 : percentage > 90 ? 9 : (int)(percentage / 10)];`

Comment: im not that advanced yet :P

Answer (score 2):

Change the function `GradeFromPercentage`, you were assigning `char*` instead of `char`

```
char GradeFromPercentage(float percentage)
{

    char grade;
    if (percentage >= 90)
    {
        grade = 'A';
    }
    else if (percentage >= 70)
    {
        grade = 'B';
    }
    else if (percentage >= 50)
    {
        grade = 'C';
    }
    else if (percentage >= 30)
    {
        grade = 'D';
    }
    else
    {
        grade = 'F';
    }
    return grade;
}
```

Comment: `you were returning char*`...umm..no... problem is in the assignment itself.

Comment: didn't get you @SouravGhosh